# Why can I see some desktop icons only with Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, desktop

If I navigate to the desktop using Windows Explorer in Windows XP, I see an Internet Explorer icon in the list along with all the other icons on the desktop.

For some reason, when looking at the standard desktop without using Windows Explorer, I see all the icons I saw when looking at the desktop using Windows Explorer, *except* for the Internet Explorer icon.

Why is that and how can I make visible that icon which can be seen from Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this Microsoft Fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945402). Depending on how the icon is setup, could be why it's not showing up, is it under the all users folder? Is it a shortcut?

Comment: Nope, it's not under the all users folder and it's not a shortcut.

Comment: Should still be able to use the Microsoft Fix. The IE desktop icon works a little different than most other shortcuts.